# TensorFlow Lite GPU delegate failure

Tags: android, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to use **TensorFlow Lite** with GPU delegate on Android. I am using the lib version (*.so* files) built from sources from the **master** branch of the repo. The problem is: the **ModifyGraphWithDelegate** function always returns error. And there is the following error message in logs:

```
2019-04-22 15:21:16.212 688-688/com.my.app E/tflite: TfLiteGpuDelegate Prepare: Shader compilation failed: ERROR: 0:6: 'unknown' : not a legal layout qualifier id 
    ERROR: 0:6: 'unknown' : Syntax error:  syntax error
    INTERNAL ERROR: no main() function!
    ERROR: 2 compilation errors.  No code generated.
2019-04-22 15:21:16.212 688-688/com.my.app E/tflite: Node number 54 (TfLiteGpuDelegate) failed to prepare.
```

If I use JAVA/JNI prebuilt lib version ('org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-gpu-experimental') like in official example project - there are no such errors. But I really need to use C++ interface for my cross-platform code.

Any thoughts / suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Hello How did you build gpu delegate with c++ inteface for android? I don't see any docs for the same in tf repo.

Comment: Check the corresponding [BUILD](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/BUILD) file. There is a **cc_binary** target with name = "libtensorflowlite_gpu_gl.so" at the bottom and the build command line example above it. You also will need to add **soname** argument to **linkopts** in order to allow proper library loading in runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it work. The internal reason of the error is still completely unknown for me but the point is:

- The used (master branch) version of the TFLite GPU delegate for Android fails to properly prepare for running on GPU the standard (for regression task) output nodes combination = flatten + dense.
- If replace it with reshape + convolution (pointwise) + squeeze, then it works fine.

Comment: I keep getting `error: undefined reference to 'TfLiteGpuDelegateV2Delete` when linking to GPU delegates, while libtensorflowlite.so CPU version still works. Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

If you're building native shared library then you might need to manually load the .so library.
See https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!topic/tflite/5YhFsCFtKi4

Comment: I do so for sure. Library is loaded and its functions are available. The error appears during the function call.